# Prove $\sum \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}$ or $\sum \frac{b_n}{\sqrt n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I need some help/hint with the following:

> Let $a_n, b_n$ be two positive sequences s.t. $\sum a_n b_n$
> converges.
>
> Prove:
>
> $\sum \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}$ or $\sum \frac{b_n}{\sqrt n}$ converges.

What I wanted to show, Is that $a_n$ or $b_n$ must be smaller then $1/\sqrt n$ (Due to the convergence of the series above) so we get that atleast one of the series above must converge, but im not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 6):

The statement is not true. As a counterexample, consider $$a_n = b_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(n)}$$

Comment: They have to be monotinoc. Edited.

Comment: @aaabbb How do you know that ? Are you the OP ?

Comment: Yes. The question was sent from my pc, This is my phone.

Comment: @aaabbb Still not true.